# Eclipse deleted every project and file

Tags: java, eclipse

I just encountered a HUGE problem w/ eclipse. It deleted EVERY SINGLE file in EVERY SINGLE project in my workspace. No Joke. I have nothing but the .project files. When I tried to restore from local history it said there was nothing. I made a backup but somehow that got deleted as well. I'm starting to think that Eclipse is NOT reliable because this is the second time this has happened to me. Is there a way to get the projects back ? because I had a project that I had been working on for about 3 months and I need it. I use Windows 8.1 Update 1 if that changes anything.

Comment: You can use an application to recover deleted files (just search for *recover deleted files* in your favorite SEO and you will get plenty of apps that do this). And I don't think this is Eclipse's (nor any other IDE) doing, but your own OS or another application.

Comment: Pro tip: use source control.

Comment: What version of *Eclipse* is doing this?

Comment: Im using Kepler Version 4.3.2